# Height of the select option box

Tags: html, css

I have a form in which one input field is select  and it has few option.I am not able to increase the height of the option box and background color.presently it has white colour as given in the picture [image: 1] My html code and css code is below

```css
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 4px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.select2 option{
    width: 26px;
    background-color: none ;
    border: none;
    background: none;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight:bold;
   float: left;
  margin: 0 10px;
  white-sapce: no-wrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.select2 after {
  !content: 'Select Role';
  font-family: 'material icons';
  font-size: 24px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<div class="select2">
  <i class="fas fa-user-lock" style="color:black; padding:10px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Role</i>
  <select >
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="user">USER</option>
  <option value="rec">Recommending Officer</option>
  <option value="store">Store</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: your css is wrong `.select2 after`  some `::` are missing !

Comment: also `!content`  and `white-sapce` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to increase height:

```
.select2 select{
  height: 50px;
background: transparent;
}
```

Add more properties here to style the box.
Also correct way to use before and after is :

```
.select2::after {
....
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tusharshahi/pen/xxdZjvE)

Comment: height is working but color property not working ,i want it transparent

Comment: Because you are targetting the wrong element. You are changing styles for div with select2 class. You have to style <select>. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving style to select tag, this might works!

```
select{
    width: 50%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.select2 {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  margin: 4px 0;

}

select{
  height:30px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```